# Golang , mongodb can not do select

Tags: mongodb, select, go, mgo

In my case I have a  collection where I have stored a data with a  structure that below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ad187a0447d3617fb802b8"), 
    "fid" : ObjectId("59ad187a6b9600120bd03a53"), 
    "pr" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ad187a6b9600120bd03a53"), 
            "trashed" : false
        }
    ], 
    "ch" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ad18a36b9600120bd03a57"), 
            "trashed" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ad18a36b9600120bd03a99"), 
            "trashed" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ad18a36b9600120bd03a98"), 
            "trashed" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ad18a36b9600120bd03a97"), 
            "trashed" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

So I want to get all objects  in `ch` where trashed is `false`

Here is my query

```
       type ChildParentsData struct {
       Id      bson.ObjectId `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
       Trashed bool          `json:"trashed" bson:"trashed"`
       }
        var tree []ChildParentsData
        err := Connection.Session.DB("cctv_storage").C("tree").Find(
               bson.M{
                  "fid": bson.ObjectIdHex(id), "ch.trashed": false
               }).Select(
               bson.M{
                  "ch.$": 1
                }).All(&tree)
```

But as a response I am getting all data, but I need only `objects` in `ch`

Comment: `Find` returns a whole document that matches the conditions. In your case the conditions are: `fid` equals to some `id`, and `ch` has at least one sub-document with `trashed` equals to `false`. You need to either process the result on the client side, or use [aggregation framework](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Pipe).

Comment: What's the expected result ? One big array with all `ch` items where `trashed` is false ? Several documents with filtered `ch` array ? you should post the  `ChildParentsData` structure to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you @felix , I have already added the struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the aggregation framework, thanks to the **`$replaceRoot`** operator introduced in **MongoDB 3.4**

We first get matching documents for the specific `fid`, then we unwind the array and remove docmuments where `ch.trashed` is true. Finally, we remove the `ch` field by promoting the content of `ch` as root of the document

Here is the code to achieve this:

```
type ChildParentsData struct {
        Id      bson.ObjectId `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Trashed bool          `json:"trashed" bson:"trashed"`
}
var tree []ChildParentsData

pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"fid": bson.ObjectIdHex("59ad187a6b9600120bd03a53")}},
    {"$unwind": "$ch"},
    {"$match": bson.M{"ch.trashed": false}},
    {"$replaceRoot": bson.M{"newRoot": "$ch"}}}

err = Connection.Session.DB("cctv_storage").C("tree").Pipe(pipeline).All(&tree)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    os.Exit(0)
}
fmt.Printf("doc: %v", tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

An quick way to get the particular fields instead of all the fileds is using projection. An example of golang is here:

```
    filter := bson.D{{"_id" , bson.ObjectIdHex("59ad187a6b9600120bd03a53")}}
    projection := bson.D{{"ch", 0}}
    collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter, options.FindOne())
```